# Cygdrive Terminal error : opus/src/opus.o failed make

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, telegram

I am importing the [Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) android application into the android studio.

This project contains many `.C` files, SO i had to convert this C files with **Android NDK** to generate lib folder, And finally end up the importing process!

But! I have problem with using [Cygdrive](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html) commend.

I see this error :

```
$ $ndkbuild [armeabi] Compile arm    : tmessages.17 <= opus.c /bin/sh:
/cygdrive/h/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc:
No such file or directory
/cygdrive/h/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.mk:464: recipe
for target
'/cygdrive/d/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/objs/tmessages.17/./opus/src/opus.o'
failed make: ***
[/cygdrive/d/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/objs/tmessages.17/./opus/src/opus.o]
Error 127
```

This is freaking me out! What should i do?

Comment: Also, my NDK is lasttest version.

Comment: Are you sure the directory exists? `/cygdrive/h/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/`

Comment: Forget Cygwin. Use `ndk-build.cmd ndk-build -C D:\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni` from Windows command line

Answer (score 1):

**/cygdrive/h/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory**

Have you navigated to this folder/file yourself and verified that:

1. The folder/file is there.
2. Permissions to access/execute are there.